# Git curl command gives me an error "could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process,"

Tags: git, ssl, curl, puppet-enterprise

I am new to Linux, Git,openssl.

I have to execute curl command in order to execute Puppet API, So I have installed the Git on TS (windows box) and trying to execute curl command (https url) along with certs path,key path and ca.pem file path but i am getting below error.

```
"could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)"


Command is below what I tried to execute:-
 curl 'https://cmp-cd-pupt.cmpcd.lcl:443/classifier-api/v1/groups' \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   --cert /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/cmp-cd-pupt.cmpcd.lcl.pem \
   --key /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/pricate_key_cmp-cd-pupt.cmpcd.lcl.pem \
   --cacert /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem
```

I checked my cert file paths are correct.

I don't know whats wrong here. I checked that on Git command prompt i have openssl, but in google i found that Git does not use the openssl. I searched many places but did not get any fix.

Please help here what I can do to fix my problem? or Do I need to use the Curl.exe if that way it works.

Please help..:)

Comment: The file really is named `pricate_key_*`?

Comment: yeah, I have double verified that. anyway i achieved this by installing curl.exe and openssl.thanks robert